# Identity selector for element.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

I'm writing an application where I am storing relative references to elements as a CSS selector suitable for passing into querySelector.  When I want to store a relative reference to the "base" element, I would like to have a selector that will return that same element.

What is the identity selector for the `querySelector` method of an `Element` as defined in the [Level 1 Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) that satisfies the following?

```
var identitySelector = "<this is the selector I want to know>"

for (int i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
    var elem = document.all[i];
    if (elem !== elem.querySelector(identitySelector)) {
        throw identitySelector + " is not the identity selector";
    }
}
```

---

Update:

As this selector isn't available, I'm going to wrap my call to querySelector with a function that returns the context element if the selector is equal to the pseudo-class `:root`.

```
var identitySelector = ":root"

var querySelectorProxy = function(elem, selector) {
    return selector === ':root' ? elem: elem.querySelector(identitySelector);
}

for (int i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
    var elem = document.all[i];
    if (elem !== querySelectorProxy(elem, selector)) {
        throw identitySelector + " is not the identity selector";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one.

---

John Resig provided a [link to a discussion](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapi/2008Apr/thread.html#msg251) in his blog topic [Thoughts on querySelectorAll](http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall).

His beef is that while you can search from any element node, the selector you pass takes in to consideration the entire document. *(Personally, I think this is the right approach.)* Because of this, he was hoping there would be an identity selector like you're describing.

jQuery (Sizzle) uses a bit of a hack by using the ID of an element (or assigning a temporary one if not available) and reconstructing the selector to prepend that ID selector.

Something like this:

```
var identitySelector = "<this is the selector I want to know>"

for (int i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
    var elem = document.all[i],
        needs_id = false;
    if( !elem.id ) {
        needs_id = true;
        elem.id = '___some___obscure___value___';
    }
    if (elem !== elem.querySelector( '#' + elem.id )) {
        throw identitySelector + " is not the identity selector";
    }
    if( needs_id ) {
        elem.id = null;
    }
}
```

...though I don't know what this would accomplish here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  As a work-around in my application, I'm going to persist a null or missing selector translated to the proposed ":root" pseudo-element selector, and wrap my call to querySelector to handle that input.